# Enable Spring Expression Language when using custom FilterSecurityInterceptor

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using spring security in my project and configuring custom FilterSecurityInterceptor to have url from database. When i am trying to use security tag in jsp than it throwing me following error.

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'hasRole' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:246)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:48)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11)
    at org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AbstractAuthorizeTag.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AbstractAuthorizeTag.java:184)
    at org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AbstractAuthorizeTag.authorize(AbstractAuthorizeTag.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.JspAuthorizeTag.doStartTag(JspAuthorizeTag.java:54)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.header_jsp._jspx_meth_sec_005fauthorize_005f1(header_jsp.java:292)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.header_jsp._jspx_meth_sec_005fauthorize_005f0(header_jsp.java:227)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:137)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(template_jsp.java:160)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:108)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)



and my code of jsp is as follows :-

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="sec" %>
<%@page import="com.medshastra.security.util.AccountUtil" %>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".nav-collapse"> <i class="icon-tasks"></i> </a> <a
                href="#" class="brand">MedShastra....healing touch</a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="<%=application.getContextPath()%>"><i class="icon-home">
                    </a></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Doctors <i class="caret"></i>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Near by Doctors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Search a Doctor</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Alopathic Doctors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Homeopathy Doctors</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ayurvedic Doctors</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Chemists</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a>
                    </li>

                    <%
                    if(AccountUtil.getLoggedInAccount()==null) {
                    %>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<c:url value='/login'/>">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <%
                    }
                    %>              
                    <sec:authentication property="principal" var="principal"/>

                    <sec:authorize access="fullyAuthenticated">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Module <i class="caret"></i>
                    </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="<c:url value='/displayApi'/>">Api</a>
                            </li>
                            <sec:authorize access="hasRole['ROLE_USER']"></sec:authorize>
                            <li><a href="<c:url value='/displayAvailability'/>">Availability</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="<c:url value='/displayDose'/>">Dose</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="<c:url value='/displayPrecautions'/>">Precautions</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="<c:url value='/displayTherapeuticCategory'/>">Therapeutic
                                    Category</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    </sec:authorize>

                    <sec:authorize access="fullyAuthenticated">                 
                    <li>
                        <a href="<c:url value='/logout'/>">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                    </sec:authorize>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



Security file configuration as follows :-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


     <!-- <security:http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/search/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/displayDetail/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/createAccount/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/checkEmail/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/activateUser/**"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="fullyAuthenticated" /> 


        <security:session-management
            session-fixation-protection="newSession" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="processingFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="logoutFilter"
            position="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="filterSecurityInterceptor" after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>   

    </security:http>  -->


    <bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">

        <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
             <security:filter-chain pattern="/resources/**" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/index.jsp" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/login/**" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/search/**" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/displayDetail/**" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/createAccount/**" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/activateUser/**" filters="none" />
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="
        securityContextPersistenceFilter,
        logoutFilter,
        processingFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></property>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="affirmativeBased"></property>
        <property name="securityMetadataSource"
            ref="optionsFromDataBaseFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource"></property>
        <property name="validateConfigAttributes" value="true" />           
    </bean>

    <bean id="optionsFromDataBaseFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource"
        class="com.medshastra.security.config.DataBaseFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource"></bean>

    <bean id="affirmativeBased"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionCreation">
        </constructor-arg>  
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionCreation"
        class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
        <!-- <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='true' /> -->
    </bean>


    <!-- Basic authentication filter. -->
    <bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" /> 

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <property name="accessDeniedHandler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.medshastra.security.config.AuthenticationProviderExtended">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"></property>
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"></property>
        <property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="processingFilter"
        class="com.medshastra.security.config.FormBasedProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
        <property name="allowSessionCreation" value="true" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/performLogin" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        class="com.medshastra.security.config.AuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="com.medshastra.security.config.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <constructor-arg value="/login" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService"
        class="com.medshastra.security.config.MyCustomUserDetailsService">
    </bean>

    <bean id="myLogoutHandler" class="com.medshastra.security.config.MyLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <!-- if logout succeed then this is the URL -->
        <constructor-arg value="/login" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="myLogoutHandler" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <!-- Logout filter will be called when detected /logout.jsp call -->
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout" />
    </bean>




    <!-- <security:authentication-manager> <security:authentication-provider> 
        <security:user-service> <security:user name="mkyong" authorities="ROLE_USER" 
        password="123456"/> </security:user-service> </security:authentication-provider> 
        </security:authentication-manager> -->
    <!-- <authentication-manager> <authentication-provider> <user-service> <user 
        name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> </user-service> 
        </authentication-provider> </authentication-manager> -->


    <bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="256"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="saltSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: How does your security tag in jsp look like?

Comment: <sec:authorize access="fullyAuthenticated"></sec:authorize>

Answer (score 0):

Change `hasRole['ROLE_USER']` to `hasRole('ROLE_USER')`.